# Peskin and Schroeder, velocity $v=\frac{k}{E}$

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, dispersion

On page 105 of Peskin and Schroeder equation 4.77 page 105, Peskin and Schroeder says the velocity $v_A$ is given by $$v_A=\frac{k_A^z}{E_A},$$ can someone please explain to me why this is true?

Here $E$ is the energy and $k_A^z$ is the $z$ component of the moomentum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the particle $A$ is massive this follows from the usual formulas for the three-momentum and the energy in relativistic kinematics
$$ p = \gamma mv \\ E = \gamma m$$ with $c = 1.$ If $A$ is massless one can convince oneself that the result is still plausible, as the ratio does not depend on mass so we can take $m \to 0$ at the end, alternatively one can write the four-momentum of a massless particle
$$ p^\mu = (E, 0, 0, p_z) $$ and then from the condition $p^\mu p_\mu = 0$ we recover that the magnitude $|p_z/E| = 1,$ which is the speed of light.